# obtener url de drive para descargar archivo compartido

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

el archivo se sube sin problemas a drive y se guarda en la base de datos en una carpeta especifica

pero me esta guardando mal el webcontenlink

```
function insertaArchivoDrive($service, $nombre_estudio, $folderId, $data,$ruta){
    // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.

    function leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo){
        $totalBytes = 0;
        $pedazoGigante = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $pedazo = fread($fp, 8192);
            $totalBytes += strlen($pedazo);
            $pedazoGigante .= $pedazo;
            if ($totalBytes >= $bytesDelPedazo) {
                return $pedazoGigante;
            }
        }
        return $pedazoGigante;
    }

    $archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $nombre_estudio,
        'description' => 'A test zip',
        'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
        'fields' => 'id, webContentLink',
        'parents' => [$folderId]
    ));
   /* $archivoDrive->setName($nombre_estudio);
    $archivoDrive->setDescription('A test zip');
    $archivoDrive->setMimeType('application/zip');*/

    $bytesDelPedazo = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //128Kbs

    $paramsOpc = array(
        'fields' => '*'
    );

    $this->client->setDefer(true);
    $solicitud = $service->files->create($archivoDrive,$paramsOpc);        
    $multimedia = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $this->client,
        $solicitud,
        "application/zip",
        null,
        true,
        $bytesDelPedazo
    );
    $multimedia->setFileSize(filesize($ruta));

    $estado = false;
    $fp = fopen($ruta, "rb");
    while (!$estado && !feof($fp)) {
        // leemos hasta que dejamos de obtener $bytesDelPedazo del $archivoLocal
        $pedazo = leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo);
        $estado = $multimedia->nextChunk($pedazo);
    }
    /*echo "Id del archvio: " . $estado->id;
echo "Folder del archivo: " . $estado->parents[0];*/
    //var_dump($estado);
    return $estado;
```

deberia guardarse de esta forma

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1kV0JxycWRTq2PycXz5nO7KW7L5OERFYl&export=download
```

pero lo guarda asi

```
https://drive.google.com/a/futbolistas.com.mx/uc?id=16BccqEQh5yzBZ2pNJT6DlCThffO6b7Y2&export=download
```

con etsa funcion lo obtengo

```
$webcontentlink = $createdFile->getWebContentLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

ya no me quize complicar y remplaze el texto  por un espacio en blanco

```
$webcontentlink = str_replace("a/futbolistas.com.mx/", "", $webcontentlink);
```